# Probability of watching exactly a show out of $3$. doubt in the reasoning

Tags: probability

I'm given the following hypothesis.

> Assume that in a town, $35 \%$ of residents watch show $A$, $40\%$ watch show $B$ and $50\%$ show $C$. Assume that ALL residents watch at least one show. You can assume that the three events are independent. What's the probability that a person watches ONLY one show?

My idea was to compute $$P(\text{watches only } A) = 1-P(B \cup C)$$ since if a person watches neither show $B$ or show $C$, it must watch ONLY show $A$ (we are assuming everyone watch at least a show). Similarly for $P(\text{watches only } B)$ and $P(\text{watches only } C)$ and then sum.

But If I compute the probability of watching only $1$ show in this way, it turns out to be greater than $1$ and therefore wrong.

Where is the error?

> Suppose then I'm given that the probability of watching exactly $2$ shows is $18\%$, what is the probability of watching all of three shows?

In this case I'd do $$1-P(\text{watches only } 1 \text{ show})-0,18$$ Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* assume that the events are independent *and* everyone watches at least one show.   These constraints are inconsistent.

Comment: yes, and the other two are $0,325$ and $0,39$

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've seen now the new version of your answer. do you care elaborate a little why the constraints are inconsistent?

Comment: Because if everyone watches at least one show, then $\mathsf P(A\mid (B\cup C)^\complement)=0$ which is not $\mathsf P(A)$ so the events cannot be mutually independent.